# Magento-2.0.15: Ui-Component Ui Element Ui-select not looking properly and showing two label

Tags: adminhtml, magento-2.0, forms, uicomponent, ui-select

I am trying to create a ui-select element using ui-component form, for fullfil my requirement in admin section.

I have written code as below:

```
<field name="vendor_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">[...]\[...]\Model\Source\Vendor</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign to Vendor</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean" >true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean" >false</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean" >false</item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
                </item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">event_info</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>  
            </item>
        </argument>
</field>
```

And the result of the above code is shown below with marked issue:
[image]

Issues are:

1) Two label as "Assign to vendor" is incorrect

2) Select box width is so small may be due to second label

3) I have made `showCheckbox` to `false` so checkbox should not be there.

4) Filter/search is happen on click on search icon or press enter but not by enter key for search.

Can Anyone suggest what I should add to the above code for fullfil my requirements and what wrong I am doing.

I have looked into many post like below but not resolved my issue.

[UiComponent Ui Element Ui-select Not Properly Working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165395/uicomponent-ui-element-ui-select-not-properly-working)

[How to properly populate ui-select component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132709/how-to-properly-populate-ui-select-component)

[Magento2 file reference for the component](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js)

Please note my magento version on which I am working is **magento 2.0.15**.

Please let me know in case of any query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to make it simple like:

```
<field name="vendor_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">[...]\[...]\Model\Source\Vendor</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign to Vendor</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">event_info</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>  
            </item>
        </argument>
</field>
```